# Jena; Domains and Ranges for a property differs upon selected Reasoner

Tags: java, jena, owl, reasoning, pellet

Using Jena, I am trying to get domains and ranges for a property.

Let's consider the following ontology

```
 @prefix : <http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#> .
 @prefix owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
 @prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
 @prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
 @prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
 @prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
 @base <http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82> .

<http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82> rdf:type owl:Ontology .

:P rdf:type owl:ObjectProperty ;   
   rdfs:domain :A1 ;   
   rdfs:range :B1 .

:A rdf:type owl:Class .

:A1 rdf:type owl:Class ;    
    rdfs:subClassOf :A .

:A2 rdf:type owl:Class ;    
    rdfs:subClassOf :A1 .

:B rdf:type owl:Class .

:B1 rdf:type owl:Class ;
    rdfs:subClassOf :B .

:B2 rdf:type owl:Class ;    
    rdfs:subClassOf :B1 .
```

As we can see, A1 is the domain of P and B1 is its range. According to OWL semantics we can infer that A is also a domain for P and B is also a range for it [see here](http://answers.semanticweb.com/questions/31804).

However, using Jena with a reasoner don't always give the expected behavior. Let's differentiate two situations, the first is using Pellet reasoner, and the second is using OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF

**Code**

```
import org.mindswap.pellet.jena.PelletReasonerFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntClass;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModel;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntProperty;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.Resource;
import com.hp.hpl.jena.util.iterator.ExtendedIterator;

public class Test{
    public static void main (String [] args)
{                       

    OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(PelletReasonerFactory.THE_SPEC);
    /*OntModel ontModel = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF);*/
    ontModel.read("path_to_ontology",  "RDF/XML");                              
    ontModel.setStrictMode(false); 


    String myNS = ontModel.getNsPrefixURI("");              

Resource r = ontModel.getResource(myNS + "P" );     
    OntProperty prop = (OntProperty) r.as( OntProperty.class);
    ExtendedIterator <OntClass> opDomains = (ExtendedIterator <OntClass>) prop.listDomain();                        
    while(opDomains.hasNext()){
        OntClass domain = opDomains.next();
        System.out.println("DOMAIN: " + domain.getURI());
    }       

    ExtendedIterator <OntClass> opRanges = (ExtendedIterator <OntClass>) prop.listRange();
    while(opRanges.hasNext()){
        OntClass ran = opRanges.next();
        System.out.println("RANGE: " + ran.getURI());
    }
}
}
```

**Using Pellet: this gives the following output:**

```
DOMAIN: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#A1
RANGE: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#B1
```

**Using OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF:  this gives the following output:**

```
DOMAIN: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
DOMAIN: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#A1
DOMAIN: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
DOMAIN: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#A
RANGE: http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#Thing
RANGE: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#B1
RANGE: http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#Resource
RANGE: http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#B
```

**Question:**

1- Why is this difference happenning?

2- What are the correct conclusions?

3- Is there some way to enforce Pellet to give results similar to OWL_DL_MEM_RULE_INF?

Answer (score 0):

Rather than enumerating domain and range try asking whether a property *has* a given domain or range:

```
import static com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ResourceFactory.createResource;
...
Collection<Resource> classes = Arrays.asList(
    createResource("http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#A"),
    createResource("http://www.semanticweb.org/eng.medianhilal/ontologies/2015/2/untitled-ontology-82#B")
);
...
for (Resource theClass: classes) {
    if (prop.hasRange(theClass) System.out.printf("RANGE: %s\n", theClass);
    if (prop.hasDomain(theClass) System.out.printf("DOMAIN: %s\n", theClass);
}
```

What I think you'll find is that pellet will report ranges and domains as expected. This is a difference in the way reasoners work: jena's built in reasoner is a hybrid rule engine working over rdf, whereas pellet is an OWL reasoner. In practice what this means is that the inferred triples are not obviously present.

Pellet has [an FAQ](http://clarkparsia.com/pellet/faq/single-page#different-results) which explains some of the differences, and how to extract all inferences.

Comment: My ontology is pure OWL, it has no triples (no ABox). So according to what you say, Pellet must report domains and ranges as expected!